# Null object reference error in Android app using Paypal MPL

Tags: java, android, paypal, nullreferenceexception

I'm working on an android app that uses the Paypal MPL to facilitate third-party payments.  I'm using the tutorial found here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-Android/

When I run the code, I get the following error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null
>   object reference

When running this code:

```
    private void showPayPalButton() {

  // Generate the PayPal checkout button and save it for later use
  PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
  launchPayPalButton = pp.getCheckoutButton(this, PayPal.BUTTON_278x43, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);

  // The OnClick listener for the checkout button
  launchPayPalButton.setOnClickListener(this);

  // Add the listener to the layout
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
  params.bottomMargin = 10;
  launchPayPalButton.setLayoutParams(params);
  launchPayPalButton.setId(PAYPAL_BUTTON_ID);
  ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout01)).addView(launchPayPalButton); **// Null object reference here**
  ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout01)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
}
```

I don't understand why I'm getting a null object reference error, since the `launchPaypalButton` references an instance of the Paypal Class that was created earlier in the code and thus, should not be null.

Thanks.

Edit:

Here's where I initialized `launchPaypalButton` elsewhere in my code:

```
public void initLibrary() {
    PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
    // If the library is already initialized, then we don't need to
    // initialize it again.
    if (pp == null) {
        // This is the main initialization call that takes in your Context,
        // the Application ID, and the server you would like to connect to.
        pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(this, "APP-80W284485P519543T",
                PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);

        // -- These are required settings.
        pp.setLanguage("en_US"); // Sets the language for the library.
        // --

        // -- These are a few of the optional settings.
        // Sets the fees payer. If there are fees for the transaction, this
        // person will pay for them. Possible values are FEEPAYER_SENDER,
        // FEEPAYER_PRIMARYRECEIVER, FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER, and
        // FEEPAYER_SECONDARYONLY.
        pp.setFeesPayer(PayPal.FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER);
        // Set to true if the transaction will require shipping.
        pp.setShippingEnabled(true);
        // Dynamic Amount Calculation allows you to set tax and shipping
        // amounts based on the user's shipping address. Shipping must be
        // enabled for Dynamic Amount Calculation. This also requires you to
        // create a class that implements PaymentAdjuster and Serializable.
        pp.setDynamicAmountCalculationEnabled(false);
        // --
        _paypalLibraryInit = true;
    }
}
```

The app id I'm using is from a sample app that is linked at the bottom of the tutorial I linked above.  It is the app id from the sandbox environment.

Comment: did you properly initialize `launchPayPalButton` ?

Comment: Also `initLibrary()` gets called in my `onCreate` method.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya anything else you can think of?  This is driving me crazy!